# Is this a bug in Netty 4.0.0 Alpha1?

Tags: netty

I am trying 4.0.0 Alpha1. When I tried to run FactorialServer example, I found in  method 
**BigIntegerDecoder.decode**, **in.readableBytes()** always return 0. After I debug, I found in

```
public void inboundBufferUpdated(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) throws Exception {
    callDecode(ctx, in, ctx.nextOutboundByteBuffer());
}
```

should it be?

```
 public void inboundBufferUpdated(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) throws Exception {
    callDecode(ctx, in, ctx.nextInboundByteBuffer());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes its a bug.. I will fix it asap. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed: https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/3447e8711227f83ff8d02a90078e376c3fbf5a0f

Comment: Thanks for your quick action! I have ported my project from 3.5.1 to 4.0.0. Because my RC4 decryption uses ByteToByteDecoder. Netty 4.0 is much better than before. Great works! Hope final release can come soon.